# Weibull Probability Grid in R

Tags: r, grid, weibull

I'm trying to construct a Weibull probability grid for reliability analysis with the help of the ggplot2 package in R. 
I've converted the data, i.e time and failure probability, such that the cumulative distribution function of the two parametric weibull fits a straight line in the grid.

For the y axis I've written a function that converts the double logarithmic scale displaying percentages.

Now I want to fit appropriate breaks and labels to the x axis. The unit is simply time but the axis is a logarithmic one. 
For small failure times I want the axis to be labelled and broken with integers, for example a vector like c(100, 1000, 2000, 5000).

For higher failure times( time > 5000) I want to have a switch to a logarithmic scale  10 ^(x) for x >= 4.

I have trouble in combining the two things on the x axis and hope that somebody can help me fixing this problem.

In the following there is the "interesting" part of my code. You can see that I've broken and labelled the x axis just for the logaritmic (10 ^(x)) case. But as I said I want to have the combination in one axis.
This is what I've coded till now.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(101)

# length of data vector has to be plugged in the following, i.e. how many obs are given  
data <- numeric(length = 5000)

for (sim in 1:length(data)) {
    data[sim] <- rweibull(n = 1, shape = 2.2, scale = 35000)
}

data <- data.frame(time = round(data, digits = 0), event = 1)


# Estimating failure probability for complete data with the inverse of the incomplete beta function 
# Referring to "Monte Carlo Pivotal Confidence Bounds for Weibull Analysis, with Implementations in R, p. 3 ff., Jurgen Symnyck Filip De Bal"
betaPlotPos <- function(r, n) {
    prob <- qbeta(.5, r, n - r + 1)
}

RankingData <- function(data) {
    n <- nrow(data)
    data$rank <- rank(data$time, ties.method = "first")
    data <- data[order(data$rank),]
    data <- cbind(data, beta.prob = betaPlotPos(data$rank, n))
}
data <- RankingData(data)

FTrans <- function(p) {
    log( - log(1 - p))
}

parameterOLS <- function(x, y) {
    b <- cov(log(x), FTrans(y)) / var(FTrans(y))
    a <- mean(log(x)) - b * mean(FTrans(y))
    beta.hat <- 1 / b
    eta.hat <- exp(a)
    rbind(beta.hat, eta.hat)
}
estimation <- data.frame((parameterOLS(data$time, data$beta.prob)))
colnames(estimation) <- "estimates"

rg <- function(t) {
    prob <- estimation[1, 1] * log(t) - estimation[1, 1] * log(estimation[2, 1])
}
data <- cbind(data, prob.points = rg(data$time))

scaleConverter <- function(x) {
    round((1 - (exp( - exp(x)))) * 100, digits = 3)
}

wb.grid <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = time, y = FTrans(beta.prob))) +
             geom_point(shape = 1, color = "blue", size = 1.5) +
             geom_line(aes(x = time, y = prob.points), color = "red", size = 1.2) +
             scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10 ^ as.integer(x)), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10 ^ .x))) +
             scale_y_continuous(breaks = if (data$beta.prob[length(data$beta.prob) / 2] <= .5) {
               c(-4.600149, -2.970195, -2.250367, -0.3665129, -.000328, 0.8340324, 1.097189, 1.52718, 2.220327)
               } else {
               c(-4.600149, -2.970195, -2.250367, -0.3665129)
               },
               labels = scaleConverter) +
             annotation_logticks(base = 10, sides = "b") +
             theme_bw() +
             theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 24, color = "black", face = "bold"), axis.text = element_text(size = rel(1)),
               axis.title = element_text(size = 20, color = "black"),
               panel.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 2.5), panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = .5)) +
               xlab("Lifetime in kilometer [km]") +
               ylab("Unreliability in Percent [%]") +
               ggtitle("Two Parametric Weibull Distribution")
```

Hope my language is good enough to explain my problem.

Best, 
Tim

Comment: Please share a reproducible example!

Comment: I've added an reproducible example.

Comment: Okay, so even if you are able to break the x-axis the way you want to, you would not be able to show shape of the relationship between time and y-axis as the y-axis would only go till like 1 for time < 5000. I think the best way would be to create two separate graphs and just stitch them together side by side using `multiplot` or `facet`